# How do I get rid of this jriver loop process?

Tags: raspberrypi

```
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Mar 12 10:48:51 2018 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping JRiver...
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting JRiver...
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started JRiver.
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[14859]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/mediacenter22: No such file or directory
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: jriver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 12 10:47:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit jriver.service entered failed state.
Mar 12 10:47:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: jriver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
```

Comment: To format logs, select the text in the question editor and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: This is not a log format question..it is a question about how I stop this jriver loop in systemd.

Comment: I realize that. I was telling you how to make the log in this question readable to others, which requires proper Markdown formatting.